# query never executes in mysql - no error or timeout

Tags: php, mysql, wamp

Right I have no clue what is going on here. This morning MySQL broke. Running queries in PHP caused my computer to freeze, and running them in phpmyadmin causes nothing to happen. except childishly simple queries such as selecting 7 rows from a table. That one runs just fine.

I am going to do a reinstall, but first does anyone have any idea what the problem could be?

Thanks

Comment: bummer.  This might fit better on http://superuser.com?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The MySQL index might be corrupted. [Try repairing the tables.](http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mysql/article.php/10897_3300511_2/Repairing-Database-Corruption-in-MySQL.htm)